# Add Up and down arrows to bootstrap accordion with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, accordion

My code:

```html
<div class="panel" style="margin-left: -15px;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="vgroupholder panel-title" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href=".titlePhysics" onclick="removevBgs();" style="background-color: transparent;">

                        <div class="groupicon">
                            <div class="groupicontext">P</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grouptext">
                            <div class="grouptitle">Physics</div>
                        </div>
                        <img onclick="changeArrow(this);" src="../assets/images/down.png" width="45px" style="margin-left: 240px; opacity: 1;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity='75%';" onmouseout="this.style.opacity='100%';">

                    </div>      
                </div></div>
```

```js
function changeArrow(id){
    if(id.src = '../assets/images/down.png'){
        id.src = '../assets/images/up.png';
    } else {
        id.src = '../assets/images/down.png';
    }
}
```

Currently, the arrow doesn't change.

How can I make it so that the arrow changes to up.png?

**or** even better, have it have an animation and rotate 180 degrees?

Any help would be great - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it with == rather than = inside if condition and use `getAttribute("src")` rahter than src because src give directly whole path but getAttribute gives you what inside it

```js
function changeArrow(id){
    console.log(id.src)
    if(id.getAttribute("src") == '../assets/images/down.png'){
        id.src = '../assets/images/up.png';
    } else {
        id.src = '../assets/images/down.png';
    }
}
function removevBgs(){}
```

```html
<div class="panel" style="margin-left: -15px;">
  <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="vgroupholder panel-title" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href=".titlePhysics" onclick="removevBgs();" style="background-color: transparent;">

          <div class="groupicon">
              <div class="groupicontext">P</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grouptext">
              <div class="grouptitle">Physics</div>
          </div>
          <img onclick="changeArrow(this);" src="../assets/images/down.png" width="45px" style="margin-left: 240px; opacity: 1;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity='75%';" onmouseout="this.style.opacity='100%';">

      </div>      
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks - this works great. do you know how I can add margin-top of a negative number, without having a jumpy accordion animation?